# Retrieve soap body

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have such a soap request message

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testwork/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>        
         <arg0>value</arg0>
      </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to retrieve the body from this message, thus I would like to have

```
<soapenv:Body>
          <tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>        
             <arg0>value</arg0>
          </tes:sayHelloWorldFrom>
       </soapenv:Body>
```

How can I retrieve it? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the SOAP response using Java's [XML XPath API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).

Comment: I'm not very good at that thing, could you please say what my XPath will be look like in this case?

Comment: It would be something as simple as `/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body`, which would select the `soapenv:Body` element which is a child of the `soapenv:Envelope` element which is a child of root "`/`".